# Matlab how to convert numbers to single precision floating point representation in binary

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binary representation of a number in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570710/binary-representation-of-a-number-in-matlab)

I am using matlab and would like to convert a number such as `7546.456124865` to single precision.

I've used the `single()` command, but I would like to get the binary for the single precision floating point.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You know that floating point numbers come in many different, incompatible formats, and it is in general inadvisable to use their binary form in any way?

Comment: wow, you know that floating point with single() is the IEEE 754 standard buddy.  You need to read up.

Comment: @ypnos is correct in that floating point numbers are defined as an implementation detail in many languages, including C and C++, simply because some CPUs/FPUs are (were) based on a different standard.  Nowadays, though, IEEE 754 is so universally accepted that you will probably never see an exception. Notably, MATLAB "[only runs on machines with IEEE floating-point number arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/32307)"

Comment: Interesting. Thank you Matt B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>> num2hex(single(7546.456124865))

ans =

45ebd3a6
```